# How do I pass a PHP variable from one function to another?

Tags: php, function, variables

I am trying to take a PHP variable from one static function to another as the value of the PHP variable is received using a $_GET. I am getting the customers ID and I want to use the customer ID in another function.

First Function with the $_GET:

```
static function createProject($pParamArray)
{

    $result = $pParamArray;

    $result['result'] = '';
    $result['useraccount'] = array();
    $result['updategroupcode'] = 0;
    $result['updateaccountdetails'] = 0;
    $result['updateaccountbalance'] = 0;
    $result['updategiftcardbalance'] = 0;
    $result['ssotoken'] = '';
    $result['ssoprivatedata'] = array();
    $result['assetservicedata'] = array();
    $result['ssoexpiredate'] = '';
    $result['projectname']="Personalised Parties - ".date('D M Y');
    $result['guestworkflowmode'] = 1;
    $result['cansignin'] = 0;
    $result['editprojectnameonfirstsave'] = 0;

    //grabs customer id from Magento 2
    $result['userdata'] = $_GET['customerid'];


    return $result;


}
```

Second Function where I'm trying to call the PHP variable from the other function:

```
static function initialise($pParamArray)
{   

    //create customer 
    $customerData = [
        'customer_id' => $result['userdata'] //the PHP variable I'm trying to call from the other function
    ];
}
```

How would I be able to do this. I'm relatively new to PHP.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the answer actually as simple as calling the function?

Comment: `$customerData = self::createProject($pParamArray);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a PHP variable from one function to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888733/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-from-one-function-to-another)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
static function initialise($pParamArray)
{
    // call your first function and assign returned value to `$result`
    $result = self::createProject($pParamArray);

    //create customer 
    $customerData = [
        'customer_id' => $result['userdata']
    ];
}
```